# Fixed header and scrollable body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have like 15 columns in the table.  I want to scroll both horizontal and vertical and header should be fixed when I scroll vertical.  I have tried various examples but no luck. All I see header columns are not aligning with data. Column width are not fixed as number of columns vary based on the user selection

Please guide me to the correct example.

Comment: Can you post the code you've already tried

Comment: @Pais I agree with you about submitting some code or some visual demo for the result required.

Comment: https://github.com/karaxuna/fixed-table-header

Answer (score 11, accepted):

what you could do is a bit of visual trick to achieve this,
use two div tags

```
<div class="Headers">
  <table class="NewHeader">
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="Table">
  <table class="MyTable">
    <tr>
      <th>
      </th>
      ...
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      ...
    </tr>
</div>
```

now with a bit of JavaScript or JQuery you can get the th, set its width to match the cell width, and move the th cell to the "Headers" table

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $(".MyTable th").each(function(){
        var width = $('.MyTable tr:last td:eq(' + counter + ')').width();
        $(".NewHeader tr").append(this);
        this.width = width;
        counter++;
    });
});
```

now only is left to do is to style the div "Table" with overflow, so now if you would scroll the second table the header will remain in place, i used jquery to simplify the readability, but can be done in JavaScript is same way

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sckq8/10/)

[Example with automatic vertical scroll body and header](http://jsfiddle.net/A79e2/10/)

Answer (score 11):

It's easily acheived with css. It all comes down to the following:

```
table {
    overflow-x:scroll;
}

tbody {
    max-height: /*your desired max height*/
    overflow-y:scroll;
    display:block;
}
```

Updated for IE9
[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdeEH/4/)

Comment: @MoazzamKhan yep. successfully used a couple of times in prod

Comment: @MoazzamKhan lol, forgot to add the thing i've spent three hours to locate to get the scroll to work! :D

Comment: if it works, it would solve my problems too, do you have any running code?

Comment: Did you try with more than one column?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33802/discussion-between-loki-and-moazzam-khan)

Comment: Tested [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdeEH/4/show) in IETester and there it worked well - in IE10+9+8. Also somehow i can't to resize the header to fit properly with cells inside the tbody tag, when using percentages (probably due to scrollbar). But other than that it seems to work ok. http://jsfiddle.net/ZdeEH/5/show/

Comment: Works fine in IE9. See the fiddle, as it has float:left; on tbody which makes it work ! Thanks for the wonderful solution !

Comment: The scrollbar messes up the alignment of the thead columns and the tbody columns.

Comment: @Harish I think it would help the community if you accept this as the best answer

Answer (score 2):

I have created a pure CSS solution to this problem that may work better for some people than the accepted answer (which I can't seem to get working at all). Unlike most of the other scrolling-body tables I've seen that don't require fixed widths, mine has a minimum width that is determined by its content. It will wrap text if possible to avoid overflowing its container (except in the headers, which don't allow soft-wrapping, unfortunately), but once the wrapping opportunities are used up, it won't get any narrower. That forces the parent element (usually the body tag) to handle the horizontal scrolling, which keeps the headers and columns in sync.

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/doctorDestructo/x54uraaq/)**.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="scrollingtable">
  <div>
    <div>
      <table>
        <caption>Top Caption</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><div label="Column 1"/></th>
            <th><div label="Column 2"/></th>
            <th><div label="Column 3"/></th>
            <th>
              <!--more versatile way of doing column label; requires 2 identical copies of label-->
              <div><div>Column 4</div><div>Column 4</div></div>
            </th>
            <th class="scrollbarhead"/> <!--ALWAYS ADD THIS EXTRA CELL AT END OF HEADER ROW-->
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td><td>Dolor</td><td>Sit</td><td>Amet consectetur</td></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    Faux bottom caption
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]><style>.scrollingtable > div > div > table {margin-right: 17px;}</style><![endif]-->
<style>
/*the following html and body rule sets are required only if using a % width or height*/
/*html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}*/
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto; /*if you want a fixed width, set it here, else set to auto*/
  min-width: 0/*100%*/; /*if you want a % width, set it here, else set to 0*/
  height: 188px/*100%*/; /*set table height here; can be fixed value or %*/
  min-height: 0/*104px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows + caption + thead*/
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0; /*need enough padding to make room for caption*/
  text-align: left;
}
.scrollingtable * {box-sizing: border-box;}
.scrollingtable > div {
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px; /*this determines column header height*/
}
.scrollingtable > div:before {
  top: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue; /*header row background color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div {
  min-height: 0/*43px*/; /*if using % height, make this large enough to fit scrollbar arrows*/
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll/*auto*/; /*set to auto if using fixed or % width; else scroll*/
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black; /*border around table body*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div:after {background: white;} /*match page background color*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-top: -20px; /*inverse of column header height*/
  margin-right: 17px; /*uncomment if using % width*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px; /*inverse of caption height*/
  margin-top: -1px; /*inverse of border-width*/
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > * > tr > * {padding: 0;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px; /*header cell padding*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > :first-child:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
  border-left: 1px solid black; /*leftmost header border*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div > div:first-child,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  color: white; /*header row font color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:before,
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * > div[label]:after {content: attr(label);}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > thead > tr > * + :before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-left: 1px solid black; /*borders between header cells*/
}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead {float: right;}
.scrollingtable .scrollbarhead:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: -1px; /*inverse border-width*/
  background: white; /*match page background color*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:after {
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  top: -1px; /*inverse of border width*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody {vertical-align: top;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr {background: white;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0 6px 0 6px;
  height: 20px; /*match column header height*/
}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody:last-of-type > tr:last-child > * {border-bottom: none;}
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {background: gainsboro;} /*alternate row color*/
.scrollingtable > div > div > table > tbody > tr > * + * {border-left: 1px solid black;} /*borders between body cells*/
```

---

And [here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673153/html-table-with-fixed-headers/25818428#25818428) where I answered in a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some third party table, like [YUI table](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_fixedscroll.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure javascript solution using TableAdjuster and TableData classes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      .hdrDiv
      {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      .tblDiv
      {
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 500px;
      }
      .hdr
      {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .hdr td, .tbl td
      {
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: rgb(163,163,163);
        text-align: left;
        cursor: default;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .hdr td
      {
        font: bold 12px Tahoma;
        padding-top: 4px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
      }
      .hdr td.col1
      {
        width: 20%;
      }
      .hdr td.col2
      {
        width: 20%;
      }
      .hdr td.col3
      {
        width: 25%;
      }
      .hdr td.col4
      {
        width: 35%;
      }
      .hdr, .tbl
      {
        table-layout: fixed;
        min-width: 400px;
      }
      .tbl td
      {
        font: 12px Tahoma;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var g_adjuster = null;
      var g_initRowCount = 4;

      function getScrollbarWidth()
      {
        var outer = document.createElement("div");
        outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
        outer.style.width = "100px";
        document.body.appendChild(outer);
        var widthNoScroll = outer.offsetWidth;
        outer.style.overflow = "scroll";
        var inner = document.createElement("div");
        inner.style.width = "100%";
        outer.appendChild(inner);        
        var widthWithScroll = inner.offsetWidth;
        outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);
        return widthNoScroll - widthWithScroll;
      }
      function ExtractInt(value)
      {
        var regExp = /([a-zA-Z])/g;
        value = value.replace(regExp, "");
        return (value.length == 0) ? 0 : parseInt(value);
      }
      function TableData(hdrID, tableID)
      {
        this.m_hdrID = hdrID;
        this.m_tableID = tableID;
        this.m_pbWidth = 0;
        var header = document.getElementById(this.m_hdrID);
        var table = document.getElementById(this.m_tableID);
        this.m_hasSB = table ? (table.parentNode.scrollHeight > table.parentNode.clientHeight) : false;
        var hdrRow = (header != null && header.rows.length > 0) ? header.rows[0] : null;
        var clsName = !hdrRow ? "" : (hdrRow.className.length > 0) ? hdrRow.className : (header.className.length > 0) ? header.className + " td" : "";
        var elements = [];
        elements.push({ prop: 'padding-left', value: ''});
        elements.push({ prop: 'padding-right', value: ''});
        elements.push({ prop: 'border-width', value: ''});
        this.GetCSSValues('.' + clsName, elements);
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
        {
          var w = ExtractInt(elements[i].value);
          if (elements[i].prop == 'border-width')
            w *= 2;
          this.m_pbWidth += w;
        }
      }
      TableData.prototype.GetCSSValues = 
        function(theClass, elements)
      {
        var classLower = theClass.toLowerCase();
        var cssRules;
        for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
        {
          var found = true;
          try
          {
            if (document.styleSheets[i]['rules'])
              cssRules = 'rules';
            else if (document.styleSheets[i]['cssRules'])
              cssRules = 'cssRules';
            else
            {
              found = false;
            }
          }
          catch(err)
          {
            break;
          }
          if (!found)
            continue;
          for (var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i][cssRules].length; j++)
          {
            if (typeof document.styleSheets[i][cssRules][j].selectorText != 'string')
              continue;
            var selectorLower = document.styleSheets[i][cssRules][j].selectorText.toLowerCase();
            if (selectorLower.indexOf(classLower) >= 0)
            {
              for (var k=0; k<elements.length; k++)
              {
                var v = document.styleSheets[i][cssRules][j].style.getPropertyValue(elements[k].prop);
                if (typeof v == 'string' && v.length > 0)
                  elements[k].value = v;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      TableData.prototype.Adjust = 
        function(sbWidth)
      {
        var header = document.getElementById(this.m_hdrID);
        var table = document.getElementById(this.m_tableID);
        var hdrRow = (header != null && header.rows.length > 0) ? header.rows[0] : null;
        if (!hdrRow || !table)
          return;
        var hasSB = table.parentNode.scrollHeight > table.parentNode.clientHeight;
        header.style.width = hasSB ? "calc(100% - " + sbWidth.toString() + "px)" : "100%";
        var colCount = hdrRow.cells.length;
        for (var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++)
        {
          var r = table.rows[i];
          for (var j=0; j<r.cells.length; j++)
          {
            if (j >= colCount)
              break;
            var w = hdrRow.cells[j].offsetWidth - this.m_pbWidth;
            r.cells[j].style.width = w + 'px';
          }
        }
      }
      function TableAdjuster()
      {
        this.m_sbWidth = getScrollbarWidth();
        this.m_data = [];
      }
      TableAdjuster.prototype.AddTable = 
        function(hdrID, tableID)
      {
        // We can have multiple scrollable tables on the page
        this.m_data.push(new TableData(hdrID, tableID));
      }
      TableAdjuster.prototype.Adjust = 
        function()
      {
        for (var i=0; i<this.m_data.length; i++)
          this.m_data[i].Adjust(this.m_sbWidth);
      }
      function DeleteRow()
      {
        var table = document.getElementById("tablebody");
        if (table != null && table.rows.length > 0)
          table.deleteRow(table.rows.length-1);
        AdjustSize();
      }
      function AddRow(adjust)
      {
        var header = document.getElementById("header");
        var table = document.getElementById("tablebody");
        var hdrRow = (header != null && header.rows.length > 0) ? header.rows[0] : null;
        if (!hdrRow || !table)
          return;
        var colCount = hdrRow.cells.length;
        var rowNum = table.rows.length + 1;
        var r = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var i=0; i<colCount; i++)
        {
          var c = r.insertCell(-1);
          c.innerHTML = "Row " + rowNum.toString() + " Column " + (i + 1).toString() + " content";
        }
        if (adjust)
          AdjustSize();
      }
      function AdjustSize()
      {
        g_adjuster.Adjust();
      }
      function InitPage()
      {
        for (var i=0; i<g_initRowCount; i++)
          AddRow(false);
        g_adjuster = new TableAdjuster();
        g_adjuster.AddTable("header", "tablebody");
        AdjustSize();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="InitPage()" onresize="AdjustSize()">
    <div id="headerDiv" class="hdrDiv">
      <table id="header" class="hdr">
        <tr>
          <td class="col1">Column 1 Title</td>
          <td class="col2">Column 2 Title</td>
          <td class="col3">Column 3 Title</td>
          <td class="col4">Column 4 Title</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tableDiv" class="tblDiv">
      <table id="tablebody" class="tbl">
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 12px">
      <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="AddRow(true);"/>
      <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="DeleteRow();"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found a system that is

- Compatible with Internet Explorer 9 + Chrome + Firefox (Windows) and Safari (Mac)
- Without using javascript
- Using only une div and one table
- Fixed header and footer (EXCEPT for IE), with scrollable body. Header and body with same column widths

Result:[image]

HTML:

```
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="nombre"><%= f.label :cost_center %></th>
      <th class="cabecera cc">Personal</th>
      <th class="cabecera cc">Dpto</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @cost_centers.each do |cc| %>
    <tr>
      <td class="nombre"><%= cc.nombre_corto %></td>
      <td class="cc"><%= cc.cacentrocoste %></td>
      <td class="cc"><%= cc.cacentrocoste_dpto %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><a href="#">Mostrar mas usuarios</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
div.cost_center{
  font-size:75%;
  margin-left:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height:300px;  
}

div.cost_center label { 
  float:none;
  font-size:14px;
}

div.cost_center table{
  width:300px;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  float:right;
  table-layout:fixed;
}

div.cost_center table tr{
  height:16px;
}
div.cost_center th{
  font-weight:normal;
}

div.cost_center table tbody{
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height:240px;
}

div.cost_center table thead{
  display:block;
}

div.cost_center table tfoot{
  display:block;
}
div.cost_center table tfoot td{
  width:280px;
}
div.cost_center .cc{
  width:60px;
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

div.cost_center .nombre{
  width:150px;
}
div.cost_center tbody .nombre{
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

div.cost_center table tfoot td{
 text-align:center;  
 border: 1px solid #999; 
} 

div.cost_center table th, 
div.cost_center table td { 
  padding: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

div.cost_center table tbody td {
  white-space: normal;
  font:  .8em/1.4em Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background-color: white;
}
div.cost_center table th.cabecera { 
  font:  0.8em/1.4em Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFEAB5;
}
```